# Is it possible to modify any function $f(x)$ such that the new function yields only the real component $\Re[f(x)]$ of the original function?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

For example, suppose that you have the function, $f(x) = \sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x+1}$, which yields a mixture of purely real, purely imaginary and complex values. Is there an operation, or a series of operations, that could be applied to a function like this to describe only the real component of $f(x)$?

Comment: Take $\frac{1}{2}(f(x) + \overline{f(x)}).$

Comment: you mean something like `g(x) = [f(x) + f*(x)]/2`? edit: too late by 11 sec ;)

Comment: Thanks @user159517 and JHBonarius, lifesavers, haha! How would you go about finding the complex conjugate of f(x) though, or is that something that you could only do after inputting a value for x?

Comment: Like taking the real part of a (complex) number, forming the complex conjugate requires the split into real and imaginary parts.  It's a well-defined operation on all complex numbers, but yes, to "do" it requires specifying an input.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the clarification!